# tick one checkbox all checkbox get selected to delete in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, checkbox

we  need one checkbox on top on which if we select it all checkbox got selected.
    on check it is giving one array to post data .
   Is there any by default functionality in cakephpform helper or I should use here javascript.

```
<div>

      echo $this->Form->create(null, array(
     'url' => array('controller' => 'manageUsers', 'action' => 'deleteUser')
       ));

        ?>

 <table width="100%" border="1">
   <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Name</th>
         <th>Email</th>
         <th>Phone  Number</th>
            </tr>
        <?php foreach($ActiveUsers as $ActiveUser){

            ?> 


        <tr>

         <td><input type="checkbox" name ="status[]" value="<?php echo                  
            $ActiveUser['User']['id'];  ?>"></input></td>

         <td align='center'><?php echo $this->html->link($ActiveUser['User']['name'], 
          array('action' => 'editUser',$ActiveUser['User']['id']), array('escape' => 
            false));?> </td>
        <td align='center'><?php echo $ActiveUser['User']['email']; ?></td>
        <td align='center'><?php echo $ActiveUser['User']['phone']; ?></td>

        </tr>
        <?php }?>
        </table>
         <?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Delete User')); ?>

             </div>
```

Comment: In my opinion javascript solution would be faster to create.

Comment: can you provide some code so  that it can be implemented in it.

Comment: To be sure: Javascript without jQuery?

Comment: Do you have any example code working.

Comment: jQuery(1.6+): `$('.someClass').on('click', function(){ $('.myCheckboxsClass').prop('checked', true); });` Keep in mind that is simplified version

Comment: thanks i got a link for it     http://www.sanwebe.com/2014/01/how-to-select-all-deselect-checkboxes-jquery